# onLocationChange method is not executing when I move

Tags: java, android, location, android-fusedlocation

I'm trying to execute a piece of code each time within 10 meters, when I first run my app, it executes all the code inside onLocationChange, but after I move more than 10 meters it seems like the listener is not working anymore or the location is not updated, any clue on what it might be causing this issue?

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "it moved: " + location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: "+location.getLatitude()+""+location.getLongitude());
        getPlaceByTimer();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startLocationUpdate();


    }

    private void initLocationRequest() {
        mLastLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLastLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
      mLastLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    }


    private void startLocationUpdate() {

        initLocationRequest();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLastLocationRequest, this);
    }
```

`FusedLocationApi` appears to be deprecated, but what I was reading is that its working too for versions of Google Play services, so I think there is no a problem there

Answer (score 0):

it seems that adding  `mLastLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);` parameter to the mLastLocationRequest solved the update issue